# Invoke method when no observers for RxJs Subject

Tags: rxjs, observers, subject

How to invoke a method when all the observers have unsubscribed from a subject.

**Update**

```
const alphaStore = new BehaviourSubject(0);
observer1 = alphaStore.subscribe(console.log);
observer2 = alphaStore.subscribe(console.log);
```

And when all of these observers unsubscribe. I want a method to be invoked. Like...

> Observer1 unsubscribed
>
> Observer2 unsubscribed
>
> All observers left

Comment: Can you give an example of code please? It's not clear.

Comment: Updated the question with an example of code @MohamedGara

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe already does the `finalize()` operator. Better said `finalize()` calls its callback when the chain disposes which means it's called when all observers unsubscribes, the chain completes or errors.

```
const subject = new Subject();
const shared = subject.pipe(
  finalize(() => console.log('finalize')),
  share(),
);
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-rebfba

When all observers unsubscribe `share()` unsubscribes from its source which triggers `finalize()`.

Currently there's no way to distinguish why `finalize()` was invoked. See this issue https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/2823 and examples there on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom Observable, that will track the subscription count.

Heres a simple example:

```
let count = 0;

const tracked$ = new Observable(() => {
  count++;

  return ()=>{
    count--;
    if (count === 0) {
      console.log('I am empty');
    }
  };
})
```

And then merge it with Observable that does actual work.
For simplicity sake, lets imagine its just a timer

```
// const tracked$ = ...

const data$ = Observable.timer(0, 5);

const result$ = data$
  .merge(tracked$)
  .take(5)
  .subscribe(value => console.log('v:', value));
```

After 5 values were emitted -- it will log `I am empty`.

Heres a live example (with some rewrite and two subscriptions):

https://observable-playground.github.io/gist/4a7415f3528aa125fb686204041138cb

*NOTE: this code uses rxjs-compat notation, which is easier to read. Above linked example uses `.pipe` notation, which is more common now.*

Hope this helps.