# Detect Subject Observers in rxjs

Tags: rxjs, observers, subject

Is there an rxjs operator or some other method for detecting when an observer unsubscribes from a subject?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54689184/invoke-method-when-no-observers-for-rxjs-subject) talks about the `finalize` operator, but it appears to be an all-or-nothing solution that depends upon completing or erroring the subject. I also reviewed [this blog](https://blog.bitsrc.io/rxjs-subjects-in-depth-56dcfc1dc858), which talks about adding/removing observers, but doesn't touch on listening to when the `observers` array is updated.

To be clear, I want to know when an observer has chosen to unsubscribe from the subject, not when the subject is completed. If only for the sake of discussion and/or exploring less commonly used operators, feel free to get clever.

Comment: The thing that `complete` & `error` notifications have in common is that in both cases an unsubscription will take place. So, why wouldn't `finalize` work here? I think that a manual unsubscription should be 'intercepted' with the help of `finalize` as well.

Comment: You're right. I'm an idiot. I had thought I tested this before posting my question, but it turned out that my test was invalid.

Comment: No worries! I’m glad you found the answer to your question